# How to use RPG.JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to work with [this](http://rpgjs.com/) library (RPG.js) because it looks very powerfull, I looked at [the official tutorial](http://rpgjs.com/v2/doc/?p=tuto-get_started.html) but i don't understand a lot of things, State 4 : "Initialize the canvas in your JS file :", whitch one ?
Is any one already used this library or know an other powerfull ?
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually it was not so simple; I struggled I bit until I got a **minimal functional game**. What I did was not the "optimal" approach, but at least worked for me (I was using Mozilla Firefox in a Windows 7 OS). If someone knows how to improve what I did, I would be happy to know (since I'm a newbie in this library too), but since I was not able to find a good a simple starter tutorial in the net, I want to share what I did, in the hope I can help someone.

Before anything, create a HTML file, and call the libs inside the `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="canvasengine-X.Y.Z.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="rpgjs-X.Y.Z.min.js"></script>
```

And the canvas inside the `<body>` tag:

```
<canvas id="canvas_id" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

There's a 'sample' folder inside the github project (see https://github.com/RSamaium/RPG-JS), and inside this folder there is a functional game, and you can open it in the browser by the file `quick.html`. The idea is that **if the sample game can work, then you can make your game work too**, so I started trying to use the same graphics, data etc. of the sample.

First, you need to **create in the root of your project the following folders and subfolders**:

```
core
core\scene
Data
Data\Maps
Graphics
```

To have a minimal functional game, you need 1) a *map* to walk with your character, and 2) a *character* to control. So, you need to have graphics for some tiles to build your map and the walking model for your character. **Create the subfolders below:**

```
Graphics\Characters
Graphics\Tilesets
Graphics\Windowskins
```

And then **copy the following files** from the corresponding sample subfolder to these folders you created:

```
Graphics\Characters\event1.png
Graphics\Tilesets\tileset.png
Graphics\Windowskins\window.png #this file will be necessary for some of the js files below, even if not used; to remove this necessity, you'll need to edit these files - not what we want to do in the start.
```

In the 'core/scene' folder, you'll have some js files to load scenes (like the scene of your walking in the map, the gameover scene). I needed to **copy all the js files inside the corresponding folder in the 'sample' project to the 'core/scene' folder of your game**. This folder is *not* inside the 'sample' folder, but in the root of the github project. I only got my game working when I added all the 7 js files (without some work inside the codes you can remove the scenes you don't want, but since what we want is just to be able to run a simple game, let's copy them for now):

```
Scene_Gameover.js
Scene_Generated.js
Scene_Load.js
Scene_Map.js
Scene_Menu.js
Scene_Title.js
Scene_Window.js
```

Now, **I added the following code inside a `<script>` tag on the html**. This is more or less the same that was in the documentation. These codes will create an "actor" (a character), a "map", and the tiles you'll use in the map
For more details on maps or tiles, you should read the documentation (the same you linked in your question).

```
RPGJS.Materials = {
    "characters": {
        "1": "event1.png"
    },
    "tilesets": {
        "1": "tileset.png"
    }
};

RPGJS.Database = {
    "actors": {
        "1": {
            "graphic": "1"
        }
    },
    "tilesets": {
        "1": {
            "graphic": "1"
        }
    },
    "map_infos": {      
        "1": {
            "tileset_id": "1"
        }
    }
};

RPGJS.defines({
    canvas: "canvas_id",
    autoload: false
}).ready(function() {

RPGJS.Player.init({
    actor: 1,
    start: {x: 10, y: 10, id: 1} // Here, map id doesn't exist
});

RPGJS.Scene.map();
```

Lastly, create the json file setting every tile of your map. **I just copied the MAP-1.json file from the 'sample' folder to inside the `Data\Maps` folder**.

Then you'll be able to walk with your character in an empty map! Open the html file in your browser and try it!

[Printscreen from the game running in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcOCE.png)

Of course to have a real game you'll need to change a lot of this (as creating a database.json file and a materials.json file where you'll put most of the code you put in the `<script>` tag), but with the basics I hope you can work from that!

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is very clear

> 3. Add this code in your page :
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <script src="canvasengine-X.Y.Z.all.min.js"></script>
> <script src="rpgjs-X.Y.Z.min.js"></script>
> <canvas id="canvas_id" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
> ```

That's "the canvas" ^

Answer (score 0):

Brian Hellekin post a great tutorial. If you want see all the power of this library you must modify your html file in this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">


<script src="http://canvasengine.net/cdn/dev/canvasengine-latest.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rpgjs.com/cdn/rpgjs-2.0.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="plugins/gamepad.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/virtualjoystick.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/soundmanager2-jsmin.js"></script>
    <script>

    var Data = null;

    if (Data) {
        Data.database._scenes = Data.menus;
        Data.database.system = Data.settings;
    }

    RPGJS.defines({
        canvas: "canvas",
        plugins: ["/rpgjs/plugins/Hub", "/rpgjs/plugins/Arpg", "/rpgjs/plugins/MenuGenerated"],
        scene_path: "/rpgjs/",
        soundmanager: {
            url: "/rpgjs/swf/",
        },
        autoload: Data == null,
        ignoreLoadError: true
    }).ready(function(rpg) {

        var material_json = {};
        var m, type;

        if (Data) {
            for (var i in Data.materials) {

                m = Data.materials[i];
                type = m['type'] + "s";

                if (!material_json[type]) {
                    material_json[type] = {};
                }

                material_json[type][m['material_id']] = RPGJS_Canvas.Materials.getFilename(m['path'], true);
            }



            var m, e;
            var map_info = Data.maps, info;
            for (var id in Data.data_maps) {
                m = Data.data_maps[id];
                this.setMap(id, m.map.map);

                info = map_info[id];
                info.tileset_id = info.tileset;
                info.autotiles_id = info.autotiles;
                info.events = [];
                info.dynamic_event = [];

                for (var i=0 ; i < m.events.length ; i++) {
                    e = m.events[i];

                    if (e.data_event.type == "event" ) {
                        var format = 
                            [
                                {
                                    "id"    :   e.event_id,
                                    "x"     : e.position_x,
                                    "y"     : e.position_y,
                                    "name"  : 'EV-' +  e.event_id
                                },
                                e.data_event.data.pages
                            ];
                        this.setEvent(id, 'EV-' +  e.event_id, format);
                        info.events.push('EV-' +  e.event_id);
                    }
                    else {
                        var name, _id;

                        for(var key in e.data_event.data) {
                            _id = e.data_event.data[key];
                            name = key;
                            break;
                        }

                        info.dynamic_event.push({
                            "x"     : e.position_x,
                            "y"     : e.position_y,
                            "name"  : name,
                            "id"    : _id
                        });
                    }
                }

            }

            Data.database.map_infos = map_info;

            global.materials  = material_json;
            global.data = Data.database;


            global.game_player.init();

        }

        var scene = this.scene.call("Scene_Title", {
            overlay: true
        });
        scene.zIndex(0);

    }); 


</script>


<style>

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}

canvas {
    -webkit-user-select : none;
    -moz-user-select    : none;
    overflow    : hidden;
}

@font-face{
        font-family : "RPG";
        src : url("Graphics/Fonts/Philosopher-Regular.ttf");
    }
@font-face{
    font-family : "Megadeth";
    src : url("Graphics/Fonts/Elementary_Gothic_Bookhand.ttf");
}



</style>
```

```
<div id="game">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
```

Note:

/rpgjs/ is the folder where i put my project in my local server. For play the game i go to http://localhost/rpgjs/

For work you need to modify the JS file in /plugins/ directory.

/Hub/Sprite_Hub.js

use this path:

```
array.push(RPGJS.Path.getFile("pictures", "../Pictures/hub.png", "hub"));
    array.push(RPGJS.Path.getFile("pictures", "../Pictures/hp_meter.png", "hp_meter"));
    array.push(RPGJS.Path.getFile("pictures", "../Pictures/hp_number.png", "hp_number"));
    array.push(RPGJS.Path.getFile("pictures", "../Pictures/Hero_Face.png", "hero_face"));
    array.push(RPGJS.Path.getFile("pictures", "../Pictures/button_A.png", "button_a"));
    array.push(RPGJS.Path.getFile("pictures", "../Pictures/button_B.png", "button_b"));
```

is very useful debug in the first time with developer tool of google chrome. When you see 404 error on a img resourse just go to your project and search the file name. Find what js script load it and fix path.

And not...the tutorial inside library project is not clear and isn't complete...they just want sell his rpgeditor and js library is put only for promotion purpose i think.

you can see here: http://rpgworld.altervista.org/rpgjs/ my final working project. Is just a try... but you can see the power of this library.

this demo load:

1- a welcome page with new and load came
2- a custom map with one event
3- a  working event: a chest that if you open you will find 30 gold
4- a player manu: just click ESC button on keyboard

i don't know how use arpg plugin for a realtime combat event but i working on for understand of to use it.